# Appsheet calculated expired date spesifiec 2

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, mobile-application, google-appsheet

I have an Appsheet who consist of two columns, let's both named is Production Date and Expired Date. If column Production Date has 35 months of Expired Date, then how the formula in appsheet to calculated it? Let say the example, Production Date is 01/10/2023, therefore Expired Date is 01/09/2026. I want the formula to consider leap years.

Before that, i have created a formula but it is not worked. There was note "DATE function is used incorrectly."

[image]

Does anyone know the formula to solve this problem? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

You can utilize [EOMONTH()](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10107332?sjid=16331191039938948469-AP) function to consider leap year.

> calculates the last day of a month some number of months away,
> factoring in different month lengths and leap years.

### Issue:

The error you have was due to the `DATE` function on `AppSheet` having different behavior compared to `DATE` formula in `Google sheet`.

Your existing formula does work for google sheet but for AppSheet you can manipulate the date by directly calling Production Date column

You can further read the `Date and time expressions` on AppSheet [here](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10107326?sjid=9086200716011080382-AP)

### AppSheet Expression:

You can try this AppSheet expression to achieve your desired result
[image]

### Result:

[image]

### References:

[Date and time expressions](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10107326?sjid=9086200716011080382-AP)

[Google Sheet Data function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en)

Comment: I'm guessing this would fain in leap years.

Comment: thank you for your help sir, but i still not understand the number 36/12 come from?

Comment: I apologize for not explaining that part, the 36/12 is the month of expiry as per your post over the months per year.

Comment: If there is a leap year, how about it? leap years has 366 days.

Comment: I would like to further ask for clarification regarding your example above so that I can update my answer accordingly, is the production date `01/10/2023` = `January/10/2023` or `October 1,2023`? The same goes with the expired date `01/09/2026` = `January 9,2026` or `September 9,2026`?

Comment: Also does your given example production and expired date accounts the leap year already or not?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, in my example 01/10/2023 that's mean October 1,2023. In my country usually format DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: in my formula excel, as example if production date is 1-January-2024, the expiration date is 01-December-2026 (35 months expiration date). In my formula excel is "DATE(YEAR(A2); MONTH(A2)+35; DAY(A2))". A2 is column production date. 2024 is leap year.

Comment: From your given example above production date `1-January-2024- to expiration date  `01-December-2026` (35 months expiration date) does this already account for the leap year in 2024? Is this already your desired output?

Comment: yes sir, i already considering leap year.

Comment: I have updated my answer above. Feel free to ask if you have any other queries regarding the updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, sir. Big respect for you

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer